# trying to redirect after submitting data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i am trying to redirect after submitting some data into my database to example.php
i have the form and it submits perfect but cant get the redirect to work i have tried a few methods i have seen on the internet but nothing worked

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>MySQLi Create Record</title>

    </head>
<body>

<?php
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

if($action=='create'){
        //include database connection
        include 'db_connect.php';

        //write query
        $query = "insert into referb 
                                set
                                        make = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['make'])."', 
                                        model = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['model'])."',
                                        unitt  = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['unitt'])."'";

        if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
                echo " header( 'Location: example.php' ) ;";
        }else{
                echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
        }
        $mysqli->close();
}

?>

<!--we have our html form here where user information will be entered-->
<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Manufactor</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='make' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='model' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Type</td>
            <td>
            <select name='unitt'>
  <option>Laptop</option>
  <option>Computer</option>
  <option>Tablet</option>
</select></td>
        </tr>

            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='hidden' name='action' value='create' />
                <input type='submit' value='Save' />

                                <a href='index.php'>Back to index</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: header() is a php function and not an html tag. you simply have to call it like  header( 'Location: example.php' ) ;

Comment: First, even if you DID get this to work, you have to remove the space between your `header(` and `'Location:` as you have here `echo " header( 'Location: example.php' ) ;";` - it needs to read as `header('Location:` - however the correct way of doing a header redirect is `header('Location: example.php');`

Answer (score 1):

the call to header() should not be echo'd. that line should be changed to:

```
header('Location: example.php');
exit();
```

calling exit() afterards will then stop further execution of the script.

Comment: To avoid the next pitfall, this must be placed **before** any HTML output. That means the code with the redirect first, the `<html>` tag afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Do not `echo header("Location: example.php)".` 
It is a php function so you just write

```
header("Location:example.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot have echo before header or together inside the same directive/condition.

You can however setup an `if` directive.

You have `echo " header( 'Location: example.php' ) ;";`

it would need to read as `header('Location: file.php');` only.

**The correct method** of doing a header redirect is:

```
header('Location: example.php');
```

---

### You can do the following:

```
if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
    header('Location: example.php');
    }else{
            echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
        }
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

---

Visit the PHP.net on the `header()` function: **http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php**

Comment: I just read through the docs and don't see where `header( 'Location: example.php' );` with the spaces is invalid or that it will fail. Tested it locally and it works with / without spaces. Do you have a reference for this, just curious?

Comment: @Sean Yes, if you visit this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and I quote: *"you cannot use header( 'Location: ...' ) as you can't sent any output before the headers are sent."* Notice the space between `header(` and  `header(` and 'Location: ...' )`

Comment: @Sean Actually, you can't have `echo` and `header` together, because `echo` is considered as "output before headers".

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: First execute your query to insert data into database

Step 2: Close database connection

Step 3: Just put>>> header('Location: example.php');

Answer (score -4):

this a php script that redirect the user to another URL  put  this after the right condition or after instructions of your code

```
 <html>
 <?php
 header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
 exit;
 ?>
```

Comment: This will not work. [Read more why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: This is the first example in the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - and specifically says in the example - `This will give an error. Note the output above, which is before the header() call`. And before the example - `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.`